# Flavorings for clear gelatin

Tags: flavor, gelatin

I'm planning to make a sort of diorama, and the 3D nature of it is going to require suspending things in clear gelatin.

Are there flavorings that would work that wouldn't significantly affect the color and opacity of the gelatin, or its setting strength?

Comment: I have seen clear mint extracts, usually used for candy making...   this should do what you want, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of flavourings are clear to begin with.  They are colored artificially to make them look "real".  I brew beer and I have seen several alcohol-based extracts to use as flavouring that are clear.  They are pretty concentrated and are not expensive.  I have used a blueberry flavoured extract before that was clear.  Surely you can find something online.  If you are having trouble finding something, you might check a local homebrewing store or one on the internet.

Comment: Thanks ... I went with orange extract that was oil based (not alcohol) that has a decent flavor ... and I added a bit of sugar.

Comment: Also, I should mention that you need to add the flavoring while the gelatin's still hot -- if you don't, it'll cloud up.  This seems to be true with alcohol-based flavoring, too.  If you stir and give it a chance to warm back up, it'll clear, but I'm not sure if it's quite as clear as before the extract ... I'm going to have to do some experimenting.  (my many failures mean I have to try again for next year, so hopefully I'll post an update before next January)

Answer (score 5):

You can use Lorann flavors, they don't affect the clarity of gelatin:[image]

Found them here: https://gelatinartmarket.com/products/assorted-gelatin-art-flavoring-lorann-oils?variant=14121096455

Answer (score 1):

Add white grape juice/green grape juice to make the color of you jelly clear.You can also ad condensed milk to make it sweet or you can add syrup or sugar!

Comment: Condensed milk would make it white (possibly translucent), but sugar ought to keep it clear!

Comment: Hello luna and welcome! In the future, please edit your post rather than add a new one to expand on your answer. As a new user, we invite you to take the tour and visit our help pages to learn more about how the site works. Both can be found under the question mark (?) dropdown at the top of the page.

Comment: Dairy products would have the opposite effect of what I was trying to do -- although I have used a panna cotta (using coconut milk) before to place a white layer under colored gelatin to make sure the colors stood out well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add grape juice to gelatin to make grape flavored jelly.

Comment: Does this come out like the kind of Grape Jelly you would use for a peanut butter and jelly sandwich? Is there a webpage that you could link to tell us what the correct ratio would be?

Comment: @elbrant : you would use white grape juice, not concord grape.  But it still has a bit of color to it.  White grape and white cranberry tend to be more clear than apple juice, but they still have a bit of color to them.  (more noticeable when you're dealing with larger objects)

Comment: @Joe I was thinking more consistancy than color. Does combining Grape Juice and unflavored Gelatin combine to create something similar to commercial quality Grape Jelly? (I was also trying to coax our new user to expand on their answer.)

Comment: @elbrant : Maybe if you got the consistency right, but jelly is made with pectin.  Gelatin sets up much firmer at room temperature, at least at the concentrations I'm dealing with